# Realm - return array list

Tags: ios, swift, realm, swift4

I have a realm object called mood and I'm trying to return all values in the field activities as a [String] list where mood = great

My Realm object looks like:

```
Results<Mood> <0x7fce164851a0> (
    [0] Mood {
        mood = Great;
        comment = test;
        activities = Friends;
        time = 8:06 PM;
        date = 4/10/18;
        symptom = down;
    },
    [1] Mood {
        mood = Sad;
        comment = ;
        activities = Date;
        time = 6:22 PM;
        date = 4/14/18;
        symptom = up;
    },
    [2] Mood {
        mood = Sad;
        comment = ;
        activities = Date;
        time = 7:40 PM;
        date = 4/14/18;
        symptom = Night;
    },
    [3] Mood {
        mood = Sad;
        comment = ;
        activities = Date;
        time = 7:41 PM;
        date = 4/14/18;
        symptom = Dry;
    },
    [4] Mood {
        mood = Awful;
        comment = this is an example data for the app!;
        activities = Date;
        time = 2:17 PM;
        date = 4/15/18;
        symptom = Lost;
    }
)
```

and I want to return a list like

["down"]
because thats the activity where mood = great etc

I have tried:

```
func getGreatMoodActivity() -> [String]{
    let greaMoodActivity = Set(realm.objects(Mood.self).filter("mood = 'Great'") as! [String])
    return getGreatMoodActivity()
}
```

But this crashes with this error

> Could not cast value of type 'RealmSwift.Results'
>   (0x10f520810) to 'NSArray' (0x10ce35008).

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `filter` operation will keep filter the `Mood` objects matching your given criteria, so its return value will be of type `Results<Mood>` which you obviously can't convert in coercion to `Array<String>`.

It seems that you are actually trying to `map` the `Mood` objects matching your filter criteria to their `symptom` property, which is of type `String`. To achieve your goals, you need to call `map` after filtering the `Mood` objects.

Moreover, your return value is completely flawed, you want to return the array stored in the variable `greatMoodActivity` and not call your function recursively.

```
func getGreatMoodActivity() -> [String]{
    let greatMoodActivity = realm.objects(Mood.self).filter("mood = 'Great'").map({$0.symptom})
    return Array(greatMoodActivity)
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I get this error Cannot convert return expression of type 'LazyMapCollection<Results<Mood>, String>' to return type '[String]' ?